# AXFR > BIND Zone Transfer

Tags: dns, cpanel, bind

Hoping someone can provide some direction on the feasibility of this plan.

1. We currently host a number of domains with **DNSMadeEasy**.
2. We are planning to move this to our dedicated server handled by
   **cPanel**/BIND as we have implemented a redundant **DNS** infrastructure
   using a DNS cluster and a secondary DNS provider.
3. DNSMadeEasy supports **AXFR** and I was hoping to use that to copy the
   zone files for each domain directly into a BIND configuration file.

Has anyone done this or have script that can easily do this? I really don't want to have to do this manually. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you have the master zone files already and want to enable `AXFR` to a slave automatically for production use, or a copy of the zone file for yourself?

Comment: So I have used dig to generate bind zone files already. Apparently, these are compatible with bind, but, they are not compatible with cPanel. Which means that bind uses them, but cPanel can't edit the zone then. So I'm kind of stuck here and looking at having to do this all manually.

Comment: You could setup a slave `NS` and get the master to do an `AXFR` to it then you can extract the files from bind. What do you actually want to use to edit the zone? cPanel or command line?

Comment: cPanel. I already have the bind files, they just aren't compatible with cPanel.

Comment: Ahh ok. Maybe you should re-word your question to say 'I'm looking for a way to import bind zone files into cPanel or convert them into a valid import format'